# Is there a way change the Controller's name in the swagger-ui page?

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm using Swashbuckle to enable the use of swagger and swagger-ui in my WebApi project.

In the following image you can see two of my controllers shown in the swagger-ui page. These are named as they are in the C# code, however I was wondering if there was a way to change what is shown here?

This is mainly because as you can see `ManagementDashboardWidget` is not a user friendly name, so I want to change it to be user friendly.

[image: swagger-ui]

Comment: Have you tried using swagger's @Api as an annotation for your restful service class?

Comment: @Sampada I am unsure how to access that, could you give me a bit more information please?

Comment: I am sorry @API is available for swagger in Java, not in swashbuckle swagger.

Comment: You may be able to achieve your goal simply by naming the .cs file to match your intentions.  For example name your controller code file to GroupNameGoesHereController.cs and in swagger you will see the group named GroupNameGoesHere.  Unfortunately, that doesn't support spaces in the name so if you want that your better off going with alternative options.

Comment: Renaming the .cs cannot be applied in my case. For example, I have different controller classes for a same route, because of the DI instanciation which differs a lot.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use tags for that. By default Swashbuckle adds a tag with the name of the controller to every operation. You can override that with the `SwaggerOperationAttribute`. For instance, the next line replaces the default tag, Values, with the tag Test:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "Test" })]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The `Get`operation will now be put in the group `Test`.

If you want the operation to appear in multiple groups you can add more tags. For instance:

```
[SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "Test", "Release1" })]
```

will put the `Get` operation in the groups `Test` and `Release1`.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted... I just never found much documentation on that part. Thanks very much.

Comment: This works, but it still leaves the controller name as a tag in the UI, but with no actions under it.  For example, say I have `ABCController` but I've added `[SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "DEF" })]` to all routes, the UI shows "ABC" and "DEF", but there is nothing under "ABC".  How do we get rid of "ABC" altogether?

Comment: Take a look to my answer below.  I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 48):

Starting with **ASP.NET Core 6**, you can use the [`TagsAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.tagsattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) either on Controller level:

```
[Tags("entity")]
[ApiController]
public class DerivedEntitiesController : ControllerBase
{
```

or on Action level:

```
[Tags("entity")]
[HttpPut("entity/{key}")]
public IActionResult PutEntity(Guid key, [FromBody] Entity entity)
{
```

Swagger will group according to the `Tags` and respect API Versioning.

Comment: That's the best answer. FYI
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/35310
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/pull/2210

Answer (score 20):

I tried using venerik's answer, but it still kept the original controller name in the UI along with the new tag that you specify.  I also didn't like that you had to add an attribute to every function, so I came up with a solution where you only have to add an attribute to the controller.  There are two steps:

Add [`DisplayNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) on the controller:

```
[DisplayName("Your New Tag")]
public class YourController : ApiController
{
    // ...
}
```

Then in the Swagger configuration, you can override the base functionality using the `GroupActionsBy` function to pull the name that you specified in that attribute:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .EnableSwagger(c => {
    
        c.GroupActionsBy(apiDesc => {
            var attr = apiDesc
                .GetControllerAndActionAttributes<DisplayNameAttribute>()
                .FirstOrDefault();
                
            // use controller name if the attribute isn't specified
            return attr?.DisplayName ?? apiDesc.ControllerName(); 
        });
        
    })
    .EnableSwaggerUi(c => {
        // your UI config here
    });
```

`ControllerName()` is an extension method defined in the [Swagger-Net](https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net) library. If you aren't using that you can also get the controller name from `apiDesc.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName`

Comment: For me, `apiDesc.ControllerName` isn't a method. Maybe I'm using a different version of `System.Web.Http`...

Comment: @CodyStott `ControllerName()` is an extension method defined in the [Swagger-Net](https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net) library, which is another library very similar to Swashbuckle (which is what I assume you are using).  Having said that, you should able to use `apiDesc.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName` to get the controller name.

Comment: The question is for Swashbuckle not for Swagger-Net!

Answer (score 20):

Version 5 of Swashbuckle supports the following option (to be used in the call to `AddSwaggerGen()`):

```
options.TagActionsBy(api => new[] { api.GroupName });
```

This should be used in combination with the following attribute on your controllers or actions:

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "...")]
```

However, by default the group name is used to include the operation in a specific document. So this may lead to unexpected results (depends on your naming of the document in calls to `options.SwaggerDoc(name, ...)`).

To make it work you may have to add this:

```
options.DocInclusionPredicate((name, api) => true);
```

Here, for every operation, name is the name of a document and the group name is available in `api.GroupName`. To include the operation in the document regardless of its group name, simply return true.

Comment: Should probably point out that by setting the `DocInclusionPredicate` to `true` then should you need to include [Multiple Documents](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#generate-multiple-swagger-documents) in the future, then you'd need to find another way.

Answer (score 19):

By default if I have a controller called ShippingController then the swagger generated UI with name "Shipping"

I was looking to change the name of my controller to something more friendly or in another language. The best I could find was to use a SwaggerOperation attribute to change the name, but this has the limitation that it is a method level attribute and I dont really want to specify the name on every method.

So, I created a convention class to use with controller Route attribute, that we usually use on our controllers and then have the swagger use that to be the name of the controller.  Well you know there is a name property on the attribute but the generated swagger doesnt seem to use it.

**STEP 1: Create this class:**

When the app starts up it will run this and I will be able to look up the Route attribute on my controllers if they have the attribute specified and then use the name property to change the name of the Controller.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels;

namespace RestServices.Configuration.ConfigInstallers.Conventions
{
    public class ControllerDocumentationConvention : IControllerModelConvention
    {
        void IControllerModelConvention.Apply(ControllerModel controller)
        {
            if (controller == null)
                return;

            foreach (var attribute in controller.Attributes)
            {
                if (attribute.GetType() == typeof(RouteAttribute))
                {
                    var routeAttribute = (RouteAttribute)attribute;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(routeAttribute.Name))
                        controller.ControllerName = routeAttribute.Name;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**STEP 2: Startup.cs:**

Modify the StartUp.cs file and in the configure services we need to register our class in the Conventions list. See below:

```
services.AddControllers(o =>
{
   o.Conventions.Add(new ControllerDocumentationConvention());
});
```

**STEP 3: In each controller add name property in Route Attribute:**

```
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false, GroupName = "v1")]
[Route("api/Envios/{version:apiVersion}", Name =  "Envios", Order = 1)]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class ShippingController
```

Now when I run the app and my swagger is generated you can see the controller name is changed to be the same as the text in the route attributes name property.

[image]

Comment: That is very elegant. Great suggestion!

Comment: Worked a treat!

Comment: Good solution, also usable with NSwag, where `options.TagActionsBy` not available. Little improvement to not missuse `name`-property from Route-attribute, which seems not being the best matching attribute for me to use for that: I'm using the `ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute` to set the group name instead and using this attribute in the `ControllerDocumentationConvention`.

Comment: This is unbelievably neat! Should be marked as the solution. Especially because it does not touch the swagger documentation groups and tags.

Answer (score 4):

If one wants to do this at a **Controller / Class level**, the following is a very useful extract from [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/467)

> use the [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "Group")] on your controllers

Then in Startup

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
options.SwaggerDoc(version,
    new Info
    {
        Title = name,
        Version = version
    }
);

options.DocInclusionPredicate((_, api) => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(api.GroupName));

options.TagActionsBy(api => api.GroupName);
});
```

Also note that

> 5.0.0-beta of swashbuckle now includes an TagActionsBy overload that supports returning an array of tags. This should allow for the above customizations to be simplified

Comment: Does not work, Contoller is not visible anymore

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ApiExplorerSettings` annotation for your controller:

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = @"PowerBI Interface")]
public class MainController(IDataObjectRepository dataObjectRepository) : ControllerBase
{
...
```

Then you need to call these methods in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    ...
    options.DocInclusionPredicate((_, api) => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(api.GroupName));
    options.TagActionsBy(api => api.GroupName);
    ...
```

Source: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi/issues/747