# How to change controller's name in swagger-ui?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

if I have the following:

```
MySimpleTestController : ApiController
{
}
```

Is it possible to have the controller name appear as "My Simple Test" instead of "MySimpleTest" in the generated API docs?

I did a search but I mostly found ways to do it in Java using an @Api annotation but I am using C# (.net 4.5.2).

Here is [one way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076173/is-there-a-way-change-the-controllers-name-in-the-swagger-ui-page) to do it but it requires adding an annotation to every single route in the Controller which would be cumbersome as my controller has many routes. Is there a better way?

Comment: WebApi uses convention over configuration: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/software-design-paradigm-convention-over-configuration/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I ended up doing it:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class SwaggerControllerNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string ControllerName { get; private set; }

    public SwaggerControllerNameAttribute(string ctrlrName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ctrlrName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ctrlrName");
        }
        ControllerName = ctrlrName;
    }
}
```

And then add the following code to the configuration:

```
configuration.EnableSwagger(c =>
{
     c.GroupActionsBy(apiDesc =>
     {
          var attribute = apiDesc.GetControllerAndActionAttributes<SwaggerControllerNameAttribute>();
          if (attribute.Any())
          {
               return attribute.First().ControllerName;
          }
          else
          {
               return apiDesc.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
          }
     });        
}
```

And then you can do this:

```
[SwaggerControllerName("My Simple Test")]
public class MySimpleTestController : ApiController
{
}
```

Comment: yep, nice work. i have a bunch of swagger filters and extensions like this that i need to publish.

Comment: How do you do this in .NET 5?