# ASP.Net Open Api specify endpoint section

Tags: asp.net, swagger, openapi

I generate an endpoints via minimal api and also try to generate a documentation with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi` package, but I don't know how to set a section and all my endpoints appears in single section in Swagger.

By sections I mean something like that (on screenshot there are sections visible in Swagger when an endpoints are generated with controller, each section name is a controller name)
[image]

How can I specify a section for an endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076173/is-there-a-way-change-the-controllers-name-in-the-swagger-ui-page) question I found out the way to do it.

```cs
routeHandlerBuilder.WithOpenApi(x =>
{
    var tag = new OpenApiTag()
    {
        Name = "<your section name>"
    };
    x.Tags = [tag]; // in C# < 12 new List<OpenApiTag>() { tag }
}
```